# reddit OAuth2 login with Jsoup

Tags: java, linux, curl, jsoup

I created an App (https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps) and tested it with curl:

```
curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=password&username=USER&password=PASS' --user 'APP_ID:APP_SECRET' https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token
```

Working fine. But with Jsoup I keep getting the 401 error.

```
Map<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<>();
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token")
        .header("APP_ID", "APP_SECRET")
        .data(
            "grant_type", "password", 
            "username", "USER", 
            "password", "PASS"
        )
        .cookies(cookies)
        .method(Method.POST).
        execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the third line. I see you have `--user` in the curl request, so you use a basic auth. I don't see such capability in Jsoup, but you can easily roll your own implementation.

````
String basicAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode("APP_ID:APP_SECRET".toBytes());

...

.header("Authorization", basicAuth)```
````